# How to convert a string to the BigInteger type in C ++ using the BigInteger Microsoft library

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, biginteger

Unfortunately, I have a problem with the `BigInteger.Parse(String, NumberStyles)` method in the BigInteger library. I tried using it in a C++ program and it does not work. I am not sure, but perhaps it is because Microsoft doesn't provide an opportunity to work with the `Parse()` method anymore?

How can I convert a `string` to a `BigInteger` in C++?

```cpp
using namespace System::Numerics;

...

static unsigned char hexArr[] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F' };

ostringstream oss;

for (size_t i = 0; i <1024; i++)
    oss << hexArr[rand() % 16];

string str(oss.str());

// Another way to get str, but it doesn't solve the problem
//str += hexTable[rand() % 16];

result = BigInteger::Parse(str, NumberStyles::AllowHexSpecifier);  // My problem here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BigInteger::Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.parse?view=net-6.0) doesn't take a `std::string` as input. It takes a [`System::String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0) instead. See [How to: Convert Standard String to System::String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-convert-standard-string-to-system-string?view=msvc-170) in MSDN'S documentation.

For example:

```cpp
String^ str2 = gcnew String(str.c_str());
result = BigInteger::Parse(str2, NumberStyles::AllowHexSpecifier);
```